# Name of Y-like symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, letters

I can't find the name of this symbol: [image]

It doesn't seem to be a Greek letter, and I have also tried using the `\mathcal` command. Does anyone know it?

**UPDATE**

The symbol used in a context: [image]

Comment: It seems like `\Upsilon` to me...  (Greek capital letter)...

Comment: @koleygr `\Upsilon` looks different..

Comment: I think it's a `\Upsilon` in some non-starndard font.

Comment: You can search here: https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf ; it's very similar to a slanted `\Upsilon` form `anttor` font.

Comment: Have you got a bit larger material, showing the usage of this symbol? For example, a sentence "Let Y belong to `this symbol'..." may clarify the situation.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I have updated the question.

Comment: @lala_12 the photo stops the text to the worse ever point... "and $Y_i$... is ..." it is like a TV show that try to keep the suspense... ("And the winner... is...")... I don't really think that this will lead somewhere... Just a notice...

Comment: Maybe `\otherUpsilon` with `\usepackage{fourier}`

Comment: @koleygr updated.

Comment: @lala_12, As far as I searched, a response variable is usually a common lowercase or capital "y". (In the way that the independent variable is the "x") . You just need a Y-like symbol or the common Y symbol to denote your variable. I think Troy's suggestion is really close but an \Upsilon would be a good symbol too. Probably the writer have already used the common Y symbol for something else earlier and just wanted to use something similar but not the same for his new variable. I suggest Troy's answer if you want to use something really close to the original ... But if not, any Y-like is ok

Comment: There's also `\varUpsilon`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is just the uppercase Y in `mathpazo`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Let $i=1,\ldots,N$ denote the $N$ experimental units
and $Y_i$ the $i$'th response variable.
Now we also supose that we have a covariate $x_i$ for
each experimental unit.
The experiment can be with one or more factors, with or
without blocks, and almost any experimental design.
However, in order to illustrate the use of the covariate
we consider a single \linebreak
factor and a one-way analysis of a
variance model in the situation where the covariate was
not used.  Let $\mathtt{TREAT}$ be the factor in the
experiment with the $k$ levels $\mathtt{treat}_1$, $\ldots$,
$\mathtt{treat}_k$.  If $\mathtt{TREAT}_i$ denotes the
treatment of the $i$'th experimental unit, so that
$\mathtt{TREAT}_i$ is identical to one of the treatments
$\mathtt{treat}_1$, $\ldots$, $\mathtt{treat}_k$, we can write
the one-way analysis of variance model as
\[
  Y_i = \alpha(\mathtt{TREAT}_i) + \epsilon_i,
\]
supplemented with the usual assumptions that $\epsilon_1,
\ldots,\epsilon_N$ are independent and normally
distributed with the same variance $\sigma^2$.
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Please, forgive my typo(s)...  :-)